# Current IP address in use

Tags: c#, .net

I have a C# Win 7 desktop application that sends web requests using [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.110).aspx). Is there any way to find out which network adapter or NetworkInterface is used to send these requests? (There could be multiple LAN, WAN and virtual adapters.)

I don't really want to use TcpClient, UdpClient or any socket level program as it more low level and user may decide to block the ports. 
One route I am trying to pursue is to find IP address of the current request and then try to match it with the IP address from the NetworkInterface (using [NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76z13b26(v=vs.100).aspx)), but HttpClient don't tell you your IP that is used to send the requests.

Comment: One approach would be to look at the routing table (using WMI) and work out which route would get used. Basically, get the equivalent of a `ROUTE PRINT` command (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb490991.aspx). Out of interest, why is this information important to you (unless you are writing a network diagnostics tool or similar?).

Comment: One note though - the HttpClient is ultimately performing a TCP connection so whatever you can do with HttpClient you can do with TcpClient - port blocking will either block your HTTP *and* TCP connections, or neither - never just one. Finally, you can't control the route taken using TcpClient anyway, as it is even more low-level than that (it's at the IP layer).

Comment: I don't know how you can do this with HttpClient, but if you use HttpWebRequest https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx then you get a property called ServicePoint. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.servicepoint(v=vs.110).aspx. By Default HttpClient uses HttpWebRequest under the hood.

Comment: @RB I need to track if user is connected through a WiFi or LAN. It could be even a captive portal, so there may not be an 'actual connection' to the internet

Comment: @AndyJ I am looking for details of the Client, ServiceEndPoint gives details of the service if I am not wrong.

Comment: Ah, see, that's a different question to the one you asked! Let's go one step further down the rabbit hole - why do you need to find out if it's a wi-fi or wired connection? What are you going to do with that information?

Comment: @RAnand Ah, it lets you set the local IPEndPoint, rather than read it. My mistake, sorry!

Comment: @RB My application sits the system tray and monitors connection, if user connects through LAN or WiFi it will have different icons. A reliable way to find this out is to send a webrequest and check with adapter is being used. That is why the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing:

```
IPAddress localAddr = null;
try
{
    using (UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient("8.8.8.8", 0)) //connect to google dns
    {
        localAddr = ((IPEndPoint)udpClient.Client.LocalEndPoint).Address;
        udpClient.Client.Close();
        udpClient.Close();
    }
}
catch (SocketException sex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Failed to make UDP connection, no connection to DNS ? ");
}
//find all network interfaces
NetworkInterface[] nics = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
NetworkInterface activeAdapter = null;
foreach (NetworkInterface adapter in nics.Where(n => n.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up))
{
    //wifi adapter will be 'up' only if its associated with a hotspot
    IPInterfaceProperties properties = adapter.GetIPProperties();
    var match = properties.UnicastAddresses.Any(a => a.Address.Equals(localAddr));
    if (match)
    {
        activeAdapter = adapter;
        break;
    }
}
```

I had to rely on UDP client, can't find a way to get ip from [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.110).aspx)

This will get you the current 'active' network adapter that is being used to connect to internet.